# Automatically adjusting columns width with pandastable

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I use the package `pandastable` to display `dataframes` from `pandas`. I would like to adjust the width of the columns automatically, depending on the content. In the documentation (https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pandastable/core.html#Table.setRowColors) of `pandastable` there is a function `adjustColumnWidths`. However, the column remains too small, although there would be space for it in the window. I use the following code, the `Dataframe` is just an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

from pandastable import Table
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1500x1000")

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["column1"] = [1,2,32342323424342342324342332442323423234423423234999999]
df["column2"] = ["a","b","c"]
df["column3"] = ["a"*100]*3

pt = Table(frame, dataframe=df, width=300)
pt.adjustColumnWidths(limit=30)

pt.show()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the source of `pandastable`, there is an attribute `maxcellwidth` of `Table` which is set to 300 by default.  Therefore even though  you have called `adjustColumnWidths()` the width of each column cannot be greater than `maxcellwidth`.

Set `maxcellwidth` to a larger value (enough to hold the longest string):

```py
pt = Table(frame, dataframe=df, width=300, maxcellwidth=1500)
```